# Why is my second <p> tag formatted differently from my first one?

Tags: html, css, formatting

Using this HTML code:

- http://pastebin.com/ch1FPm8M

everything works fine, except that the 2 different paragraphs the `<p>`s the formatting is different, the second `<p>` is different than the first basically, what is my problem?

Comment: JSFiddle might be a better choice for sharing this code, as it provides a rendering of the code alongside the code itself: http://jsfiddle.net/42529/

Comment: Please also post your code here rather than just on an external site.

Comment: I can’t see any difference between the first and second paragraph in terms of their formatting. What difference are you seeing?

Comment: You never closed the first `<h3>`

Comment: @BillyMoat: posting HTML/CSS on Stack Overflow doesn’t always help any more than posting it on JSFiddle, unless the OP has isolated the problem bits (which is often, as here, not the case).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: well-spotted. Stick that in as an answer.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I was thinking more from the point of view of keeping everything here in one place for future reference. If an external site such as jsfiddle goes down then this page wouldn't be complete for future users.

Comment: @BillyMoat: yeah, I see your point.

Comment: Guys the OP has a reputation of 1 and ugly HTML. I suggest he is a starter. But still this question is acceptable from a "noob". Please stop downvoting them.

Answer (score 3):

Your first `<H3>` is unclosed. Close it and you’re good.

Also... why do you have two `<BIG>` tags wrapped inside the heading? That doesn’t seem like a good practice.

Comment: @Paul, thanks for the edits... I hadn't poured my first cup of coffee yet.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close the `<h3>` heading before your 1st paragraph

Answer (score 3):

The first `<h3>` tag you use is unclosed (line 18).